# Android APK re-signing :Certificate chain not validated

Tags: android, certificate, jarsigner

I am trying to re-sign the existing android application. But I get a message "This jar contains entries whose certificate chain is not validated.". Even though my jar is properly verified.

I would like to know what are the steps for re-signing the already signed application.

And, what might have been causing to get "This jar contains entries whose certificate chain is not validated."

Kindly update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it though eclipse ADT Plugin.

There File-> Export Android APK and follow the steps by entering private key. You will be able to do it this way.

Comment: Great this way I was able to re-sign my Android application.